# having this error An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm doing my final year project and i'm doing a inventory control system based on VB.net with Access database. I have this error that keeps coming up when I debug my system.

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.**

Below is the part of my code that the error exists within. This piece of coding in the form allows me to add data into the database.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Product(Item ID, Item Name, Item Type, Quantity, Min Shelf Stock, Purchase Price, Note) " & _
                        " VALUES (" & Me.txtItemID.Text & ",'" & Me.txtItemName.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.cboItemType.Text & "','" & Me.txtQuantity.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.txtMinShelfStock.Text & "','" & Me.txtPurchasePrice.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.txtNote.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Use parameters to avoid SQL injection.  You need brackets around field names with spaces in them: [Item ID].

Comment: The brackets you need are Square brackets [Item ID], [Item Name] etc... and as Lars points out use Params or you are open to SQL injection....

Comment: Please could you re-write the code with the solution. I have tried and it is still coming up with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and copy the `cmd.CommandText` and execute it directly in Access. That will tell you what's wrong with your query

Once you fix your query, start using command parameters. The following link explain how to do paramaters

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx